# xslt 3.0 parameters not being overwritten

Tags: xml, parameter-passing, xslt-3.0

Given:

```
<table>
  <title>Inspection</title>
  <tgroup/>
     <tbody>
       <row>
       <entry>
          <para>Blend well.</para>
       </entry>
       </row>
       <row>
           <entry>
              <effect effrg="cde"/>
           </entry>
        </row>
        <!-- this entry would be empty -->
       <row>
           <entry>
              <effect effrg="cde"/>
           </entry>
        </row>
       <row>
           <entry>
           <!-- first effect would create a block, second should be ignored -->
              <effect effrg="abc"/>
              <effect effrg="abc"/>
           </entry>
        </row>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I was trying to prevent an error caused by an empty `fo:table-cell`. This could happen when the only child of `<entry>` was `<effect>`, and that `effect/@effrg` matched the previous `@effrg`, because then nothing would be printed. I wanted to minimize extraneous `fo:blocks` so I thought I could use parameters as a flag:

```
<xsl:template match="entry/effect[not(*)]" priority="50"> 
    <xsl:param name="need-block" as="xs:boolean" select="true()"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="preceding-effrg" as="xs:string?">
        <xsl:call-template name="get-previous-effectivity"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:variable name="effrg" as="xs:string?" select="normalize-space(@effrg)"/>
           
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$effrg ne $preceding-effrg">
            <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="effect">
                <xsl:text>{$asterisks3} </xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@effrg"/>
            </fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="need-block"  as="xs:boolean" select="false()" tunnel="true"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$need-block="false()"/>
        <!-- any other sibling elements will create a block -->
        <xsl:when test="../*[local-name() ne 'effect']"/>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*"/> 
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:block/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="get-previous-effectivity">
        <xsl:param name="pos" as="xs:integer" select="1" />
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding::effect[$pos]/@effrg[normalize-space(.) != ''][1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

I couldn't change the value of `$need-block` in the `effect` template by passing it another value. If a default value was assigned it retained that value, and if it didn't have a default value, it remained empty, even though I confirmed the parameter passing in was `false()`. I tried tunneling, turning off tunneling, passing it from the parent and passing from a template where `$need-block` was defaulted to `false()`. When I stepped through the code it seemed to ignore the `$with-param`. I've done this in xslt 1.0, is that considered bad practice?

Comment: I wonder, given that you use XSLT 3 and seem to want to check some preceding value, you could not just use an accumulator doing that and then access the accumulator value in your comparison. You haven't really explained which values you want to compare and the code with `<xsl:variable name="effrg" as="xs:string?" select="normalize-space(@effrg)"/>` checks an attribute but also looks for an element and a different element not even shown in your input sample (`<xsl:value-of select="((preceding::effect[$pos] | preceding::effect/sbeff[$pos])/@effrg)[normalize-space(.) != ''][1]"/>`).

Comment: I don't fully understand how to setup `accumulators` so I didn't think to use them.  I removed `sbeff` from the code above.  Only if the current `@effrg` doesn't match the previous`@effrg` will it be printed. So if an `entry` has only `effect` as a child, it could result in an empty table-cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare it as a tunnel parameter in `xsl:with-param` then it will only match a parameter declared with `tunnel="yes"` in `xsl:param`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether you can't simply use an accumulator e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:mode use-accumulators="#all"/>
  
  <xsl:param name="asterisks3" as="xs:string">***</xsl:param>

  <xsl:accumulator name="last-effrg" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule phase="end" match="effect[@effrg]" select="normalize-space(@effrg)"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:template match="entry/effect[not(*)][not(normalize-space(@effrg) = accumulator-before('last-effrg'))]"> 
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:text>{$asterisks3} </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@effrg"/>
      </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>  
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will output two

```
<fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">*** cde</fo:block>
..
<fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">*** abc</fo:block>
```

I think your parameter passing fails as you neeed the parameter value in siblings, not in children or descendants.

Comment: I like but still getting empty table cells when `effect` is the only child of `entry` and `effect/@effrg` matches the preceding `effect/@effrg`. I tried adding more rules to the accumulator: `<xsl:accumulator name="last-effrg" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule phase="end" match="(sbeff | effect)[@effrg]" select="normalize-space(@effrg)"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule phase="end" match="(sbeff | effect)[@efftext]" select="normalize-space(@efftext)"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>` but I wasn't able to rewrite the template without getting ambiguous match warnings.

Comment: @Caroline, I am afraid I don't see any XSLT code creating `table-cell` at all so it is hard to tell where things go wrong. Also if there are both `effect` as well as `sbeff` elements to be taken into account you should better show a minimal but complete samples with both of them.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I appreciate your time, I'll revisit and clean this up this later. The `table-cell` is created in `entry` prior to `entry/effect` .